# Create archive page for woocommerce attribute

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, archives

I have a WooCommerce store with a selection of products. I have an attribute for brand. [image]

For some reason if I go to https://[my-domain]/brand I get a 404 page. I have flushed the permalink rewrites with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help